# Correct way to create SQL commands in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have thought of 3 ways to create a command and execute it.

1. Every command have a different method.

   ```
    public bool UserisExist(string username, string password)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\...\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select Count(*)from UsersTable where Name='" + username + "' AND Password ='" + password + "'";
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                connection.Open();
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                connection.Close();

                UserManager.ClientID = GetClientID(username);
                return (x > 0);
            }
        }

    }

    public int GetClientID(string username)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\...\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select UserID from UserInfoTable Where UserName ='" + username + "'";
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();
                    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        rdr.Read(); // read first row
                        var userId = rdr.GetInt32(0);
                        return userId;
                    }
                    else
                        return -1;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. Have 3 methods: scalar, nonquery and query. And each method receives as a parameter the command:

   ```
    public bool ExecuteScalarScalar(string command)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\...\ Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = command;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                return (x > 0);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Or 3) like the second but the method receives as parameter but, split into

```
(string tableName, string conditionColumn, string conditionValue, string columnToGet)
```

What is the correct way to do this?

For some reason the third look wrong but I don't know why.

Comment: None of which. To pass parameters, you use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). But outside that: please tell us you are _not_ storing passwords in plain text?

Comment: I'm hashing, then

Comment: I'd also highly recommend to use something like Dapper or EF / EF Core.

Comment: this is something for a school project, so security is not that important

Comment: @BartHofland the usage of each one will be used accordingly, but should I split the command into section like in the third one and combine them back to create the full command, or receive the command itself fully in one string?

Comment: None of these are what I would class as "correct", and to some extent are the db equivalent of writing your own HTTP client or JSON parser when far better already-invented-wheels are available. Learn EF for these trivial queries

Comment: Look up how to do parameterized queries.  Something like `"select Count(*)from UsersTable where Name='" + username + "' AND Password ='" + password + "'";` is an invitation to SQL Injection.  Always remember "Little Bobby Tables" (https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom).  You might want to look at Dapper

Comment: Ah. I think I understand now. If it comes to your logic, I would personally prefer your first approach: use hard-coded command texts in dedicated functions/methods. Using the second and third approaches (for dynamically building your SQL queries) probably is not as flexible and as useful as you may think.

Comment: It is possible to create wrapper functions/methods around the ADO.NET logic. Just pass the command itself (second approach) in that case. Avoid the third approach: if you pass parameters, that should be data values that should be passed to the SQL query (like the username and/or the password in your sample code). You now use string concatenation to build your SQL queries, but in a later evolutionary stadium of your software, your SQL queries will probably take SQL parameters instead. ;)

Comment: I personally like the first one more. Why? Because it makes the DB query self-contained within the method and the rest of the code just call it without even knowing the database. You could even replace it to any other data storage and the calling code won't know. Options 2 and 3 spill database details all over your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use parameters to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). i can recommend you the following pattern to execute Sql Queries:

```
var username = "testUser";
//Passwords that you don't need to know anymore should always be hashed with a salt-key before storing them in a Database this is just an example for better readability 
var password = "1234";

using (var con = new SqlConnection("ConString"))
{
  con.Open();
  using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
  {
    cmd.CommandText = "select Count(*)from UsersTable where Name = @username AND Password = @password";
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).Value = userName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).Value = password;

    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  }
}
```

It's easy to read, you can reuse the command object and everything is opened when needed and closed when not needed anymore.

Comment: Dapper would clean this up a lot, EF even more

Comment: I'm thinking using this specific example of passing in username and raw password text to db to check whether the credential pair is valid is not a great example for people to follow...

Comment: Using the `SqlParameter` constructor that takes the parameter name and the value is probably just as bad as using `AddWithValue` on the `Parameters` collection. Letting ADO.NET infer the data type from the value can be ambiguous and can cause performance issues if it chooses a wrong type. I would personally prefer to explicitly specify the data type: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).Value = userName;" (I assumed here that the username field in the database is of type VARCHAR(50).)

Comment: @CaiusJard sure i would also recommend using one of your named libs, but it might be a bit much for a beginner and the question was what is the correct way to use SqlCommand and i used this pattern for a long time before ef was released and never ran into any problem. To Markuzy yeah you're right passwords should of course always be hashed with a salt value but i just adopted op's example 1:1